# facebook sdk api 5 video thumbnail isn't setting

Tags: php, facebook, video, sdk, thumbnails

Good day everyone. I am having a problem to set the thumbnail for video through facebook sdk api 5. After the video is uploaded, but without my thumbnail. Can you help me...
Is there any way to do it? While uploading I am not having any errors. There is my code...

```
    $timer = time();
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id'  => $app_id,
        'app_secret' => $app_secret,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
    ]);
    $linkData = [
      'thumb'  => $fb->fileToUpload('http://SITE_NAME/upload/thumb.jpg'),
      'source' => $fb->videoToUpload('http://SITE_NAME/upload/test.mp4'),
      'title'  => 'VIDEO TITLE',
      'description' => 'VIDEO DESCRIPTION',

    ];
      $response = $fb->post("/me/videos", $linkData, $token);

    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
    $timer_ = time();
    echo 'Posted time in '.($timer_ - $timer).' seconds with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];
    ?>
```

Comment: First of all, you should use local file system paths, and not HTTP URLs.

Comment: how can i write it?

Comment: I have changed the code but it also doesn't change the thumbnail $linkData = [
  'thumb'  => $fb->fileToUpload(realpath('.'.'/upload/thumb.jpg')),
  'source' => $fb->videoToUpload(realpath('.'.'/upload/test.mp4')),

Comment: Is there any way to do?